# Does node.js use epoll for writes as well or only for reads?

Tags: node.js, linux

Does node.js use epoll for writes as well or only for reads?

Say for example I have 10K websocket clients and I am trying to broadcast messages from a message queue to all the 10K connected clients simultaneously. I wonder if node.js does non blocking writes to all sockets using epoll or does it use blocking write system call? Also does it even make sense to writes to sockets using epoll?

In my case latency is extremely important.

Comment: Nodejs only uses non-blocking networking (both reads and writes).  Broadcasting to 10k connected clients will still take awhile to process though as just delivering all those non-blocking writes to the OS will take some CPU and time to do.